# Execute/Reject function based on customs attribute value in dotnet core C#

Tags: c#, attributes, .net-core, custom-attributes

I'm trying to learn the attributes in C# dotnet core, so I wrote the 2 below classes.

1. `Attribute class`:

   ```
   using System;

   namespace attribute
   {
      // [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
      [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
      public class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
      {
          public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
       }


   //[MyCustom(SomeProperty = "foo bar")]
   public class Foo
   {
       [MyCustom(SomeProperty = "user")]
       internal static void fn()
       {
           Console.WriteLine("hi");
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. `Main class`:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Reflection;

   namespace attribute
   {
       public class Program
       {
           public static int Main(string[] args)
           {

               var customAttributes = (MyCustomAttribute[])typeof(Foo).GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomAttribute), true);
           if (customAttributes.Length > 0)
           {
               var myAttribute = customAttributes[0];
               string value = myAttribute.SomeProperty;
               // TODO: Do something with the value
               Console.WriteLine(value);
               if (value == "bar")
                   Foo.fn();
               else
                   Console.WriteLine("Unauthorized");
           }
           return 0;
       }
     }
   }
   ```

I need the function `Foo.fn()` to be executed if the `SomeProperty` element in the `MyCustomAttribute` is equal to `bar`.
My code work fine if I applied it into the `class level`, but not working on the `function level`

**IMPORTANT NOTE**
I'm very new to this, so any advice or feedback to improve my code, is welcomed. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your solution is to find the declared method & in that method find the attribute.

```
var customAttributes =  (MyCustomAttribute[])((typeof(Foo).GetTypeInfo())
.DeclaredMethods.Where(x => x.Name == "fn")
.FirstOrDefault())
.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomAttribute), true);
```

Comment: Thanks,  I'll check and confirm you,  but what if I wasn't to use the same attribute with many functions in different classes,  do I need to rewrite similar statement for each function,  or there is a better way to check for the attribute quercetin it's used.

Comment: you should be knowing which function to call & in which class. then it can be easily created into an extension method (I hope core supports it).