# Custom attributes declaration of multiple methods for the same attribute in C# dotnet core

Tags: c#, extension-methods, .net-core, custom-attributes

As I mentioned in my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088610/execute-reject-function-based-on-customs-attribute-value-in-dotnet-core-c-sharp), and based on the answer given by [@Abdul Rahman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4054186/abdul-rehman-sayed) I was able to call/reject the call of the function under attribute using the below code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;    // for using Where
using System.Reflection;

namespace attribute
{
public class Program
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    { 
        var customAttributes = (MyCustomAttribute[])((typeof(Foo).GetTypeInfo())
            .DeclaredMethods.Where(x => x.Name == "fn")  // my question about this
            .FirstOrDefault())
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomAttribute), true);
        if (customAttributes.Length > 0)
        {
            var myAttribute = customAttributes[0];
            string value = myAttribute.SomeProperty;
            if (value == "bar")
                Foo.fn();
            else
                Console.WriteLine("The attribute parameter is not as required");
        }
        return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

The Attribute and Foo classes are simple so far, as i'm in the learning stage:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}


public class Foo
{
    [MyCustom(SomeProperty = "bar")]
    internal static void fn()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("a function in a class");
    }

    [MyCustom(SomeProperty = "bar")]
    internal static void fn2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("another function in the same class");
    }
}

public class Foo2
{
    [MyCustom(SomeProperty = "bar")]
    internal static void fn2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("another function in a nother class");
    }
}
```

my question is about the `.DeclaredMethods.Where(x => x.Name == "fn")` do I need to repeat the same for every function I add, or there is a simple extension can do this for me, my target is simply like this, I need to check the attribute parameter, if it is matching with my input, I need the function under the attribute to start, if not matching, the function will not run. thanks

**UPDATE**
Added the sample code to the ideone.com for easy check
http://ideone.com/E9uL6r

Comment: Please also include the Foo class and attribute usage. It appears your fn() is a static method and you are just trying to invoke that static method "fn" depending on some property on the attribute?

Comment: @JanneMatikainen I added the requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your methods are static. so they dont require an object instance.

```
 static  void ExecuteFunction(Type T,string functionName, string Value)
        {
            MethodInfo m = ((T.GetTypeInfo()).DeclaredMethods.Where(x => x.Name == functionName).FirstOrDefault());
            //var customAttributes = (MyCustomAttribute[])((T.GetTypeInfo()).DeclaredMethods.Where(x => x.Name == functionName).FirstOrDefault()).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomAttribute), true);
            var customAttributes = (MyCustomAttribute[])(m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomAttribute), true));

            if (customAttributes.Length > 0)
            {
                var myAttribute = customAttributes[0];
                string value = myAttribute.SomeProperty;
                // TODO: Do something with the value
                Console.WriteLine(value);
                if (value == Value)
                {
                    m.Invoke(null, null);
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Unauthorized");
            }

        }
```

& Execute it as

```
 ExecuteFunction(typeof(Foo), "fn", "bar");
```

**Edit :**
Updated Solution based on your Error: 
You are checking for string. you should get the class based on the string & then check for methods in it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp1Core
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
    public class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }


    public class Foo
    {
        [MyCustom(SomeProperty = "bar")]
        internal static void fn()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("a function in a class");
        }

        [MyCustom(SomeProperty = "bar")]
        internal static void fn2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("another function in the same class");
        }
    }

    public class Foo2
    {
        [MyCustom(SomeProperty = "bar")]
        internal static void fn2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("another function in a nother class");
        }
    }


    public class Program
    {
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            var targetClasses = new HashSet<string>(new[] { "ConsoleApp1Core.Foo", "ConsoleApp1Core.Foo2" });
            var targetFns = new HashSet<string>(new[] { "fn", "fn2", "fn3" });
            var j = 0;
            foreach (var target in targetClasses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("_class round {0}", j++);
                var i = 0;
                foreach (var fn in targetFns)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("fn round {0}", i++);
                    Type t = Type.GetType(target);
                    var method = (t.GetTypeInfo()) // (typeof(Foo).GetTypeInfo())
                      .DeclaredMethods.Where(x => x.Name == fn).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (method != null) //return 0;
                    {
                        var customAttributes = (MyCustomAttribute[])method
                                               .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomAttribute), true);
                        if (customAttributes.Length > 0)
                        {
                            var myAttribute = customAttributes[0];
                            string value = myAttribute.SomeProperty;
                            if (value == "bar")
                                method.Invoke(null, null);
                            //  Foo.fn();;
                            else
                                Console.WriteLine("The attribute parameter is not as required");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Method not found");
                    }

                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank, I tried this, `http://ideone.com/E9uL6r` but still not getting the functions invoked

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare f.e. collection of function names that you need:

```
var targetFns = new HashSet<string>(new[] { "fn", "fn2","fn3" });
...
.DeclaredMethods.Where(x => targetFns.Contains(x.Name));
```

If amount of items in `targetFns` is small, you can use just array instead of `HashSet`.

So, to sum up:

```
var method = (typeof(Foo).GetTypeInfo())
             .DeclaredMethods.Where(x => targetFns.Contains(x.Name)).FirstOrDefault();

if (method == null) return;

var customAttributes = (MyCustomAttribute[])method.GetCustomAttributes(
                                                      typeof(MyCustomAttribute), true);
...
if (value == "bar")
   method.Invoke(null, null);
```

Comment: thanks, bit what shall I use instead of `if (value == "bar") Foo.fn();`

Comment: Thanks, what if I've different methods, like Foo and Foo2, ..see my question edit please :)

Comment: I tried using `var targetClasses = new HashSet<string>(new[] { "Foo", "Foo2" });` and `foreach (var target in targetClasses)
            { var method = (typeof(target).GetTypeInfo()) ...}` but got error at the `typeof(target)`

Comment: @HasanAYousef instead of typeof use target.GetType()

Comment: I used `var method = (target.GetType().GetTypeInfo()).DeclaredMethods.Where(x => targetFns.Contains(x.Name)).FirstOrDefault();` but the method output is `null` may be soething wrong is here" `var targetClasses = new HashSet<string>(new[] { "Foo", "Foo2" });`

Comment: Moreover, it loks the `.DeclaredMethods.Where(x => targetFns.Contains(x.Name)).FirstOrDefault();` works with the first function name only, is a loop required here?

Comment: No. In your original question you used FirstOrDefault. That's why only first method is returned. Change it to a loop: foreach(var method in ..DeclaredMethod.Where(...)).

Comment: If I removed the `.FirstOrDefualt();` I get an error, what shall I use instead of it. The error I get is`'IEnumerable<MethodInfo>' does not contain a definition for 'GetCustomAttributes' and the best extension method overload 'CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttributes(MemberInfo, Type, bool)' requires a receiver of type 'MemberInfo' [netcoreapp1.0]`

Comment: @HasanAYousef show your code, please (f.e. ideone).

Comment: I updated this, `http://ideone.com/E9uL6r` to check if the loops working, still not getting the functions invoked

Answer (score 0):

I would go around making a generic method like this

```
public static void CallMethod<T>(string methodName, string value)
{
    var method = typeof(T).GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (method == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The method not found");

        return;
    }

    foreach (var myAttribute in method.GetCustomAttributes<MyCustomAttribute>())       
    {
        if (myAttribute.SomeProperty == value)
        {
            method.Invoke(null, null);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The attribute parameter is not as required");
        }
    }
}
```

Which you can invoke

```
CallMethod<Foo>("fn", "bar");
```

Comment: No need for OfType if you use GetCustomAttributes<T>()

Comment: @CSharpie yes there is GetCustomAttributes will return Attribute[], not directly cast types.

Comment: No, it returns IEnumerable<T>, see [GetCustomAttributes<T>()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh194330(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes, but in my code sample provided the GetCustomAttributes(this MemberInfo, Type type) will return Attribute[]. I'll modify my answer to use the generic version. Weird that resharper does not refactor to use that extension if using the other signature.

Comment: thanks, I tried this, `http://ideone.com/E9uL6r` but still not getting the functions invoked